# Can you specify which cookies to set httpOnly in IIS?

Tags: iis, cookies, httponly

We have an AngularJS application which has several cookies which need to be set to secure and httponly, however we have one cookie which cannot be httponly as it tracks the progress of a download from the application. All of the information I've found on IIS seems to show how to use rewrite to unilaterally set all cookies to httponly and secure.

Is it possible to exclude cookies from the rewrite rule or are there alternative methods so that individual cookies can have httponly set or not in IIS?